# How to merge or concatenate two different datasets into one

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have a list of strings with tickers

```
tickers = [AA, GME...]
It is just an example I have a variable with 50 tickers
50_tickers = [AA,GME,FB,MSFT...] 50 of them
And I need to combine all of them following the same pattern as below
```

AA dataset looks like this

```
2021:03:21 | 33.45
2021:03:22 | 33.50
2021:03:23 | 33.60
2021:03:24 | 33.70
```

GME dataset looks like this

```
2021:03:21 | 10.45
2021:03:22 | 11.50
2021:03:23 | 12.60
2021:03:24 | 12.65
```

I want to combine these two datasets to look like this

```
time | price AA | price GME
2021:03:21 | 33.45 | 10.45
2021:03:22 | 33.50 | 11.50
2021:03:23 | 33.60 | 12.60
2021:03:24 | 33.70 | 12.65
```

Here is what I have tried

```
for combine in tickers:
df = pd.DataFrame(combine)
df.concat(df[combine])
```

I know that it doesn't work. I don't know other methods to combine two datasets into one with common time column.
I would appreciate your hint
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Not really because I have a list of 50 strings and they are not separate variable and each of them carries separate information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
df=None
flag=False
for combine in tickers:
    if not Flag:
        df = pd.DataFrame(combine)
        flag=True
    else:
        df_t = pd.DataFrame(combine)
        df = df.merge(df_t, on='time')
df
```

Comment: I don't have a variable name df_aa and df_gme

Comment: I just have a lis of strings

Comment: And can you suggest a way to do it with concat?

Comment: Sorry didn't mention that I have 50 tickers it is not just 2 of them

Comment: it works only with two tickers and not 50

Comment: what is the issue with others?

Comment: can you please explain what flag false does in this case?

Comment: Glad to hear that the solution helped, So flag is checking that if the loop is running for the first time, to use merge we need two dataset, but when first dataframe comes we do not have any to merge with it so we can use that flag to let know that this is first df and we should not merge with anything and once first iteration over it we are setting it true which will let us know that now we already have df and we can merge the incoming df to it